# Count of emails in outlook via powershell

Tags: powershell, outlook

```
$Outlook = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application  
$OutlookInbox = $Outlook.session.GetDefaultFolder(6)  
$TotalEmailCount = $OutlookInbox.ShowItemCount

While ($TotalEmailCount -eq 0)  
    {  
            Start-Sleep -s 10  
            Write-Host "Waiting for the email"  
    }  
Write-Host $TotalEmailCount
```

Initially the inbox folder is empty. Now am trying to wait till an email is received in the outlook and then print some "text" once it arrives. But when I try to run this code I always get the output as "1". Am using powershell. Any help please!

Answer (score 2):

`ShowItemCount` is the wrong property to be checking. This [returns an enumerator that defines whether outlook shows a count of unread emails on a folder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/folder-showitemcount-property-outlook), which looks to be set to "1" for you currently. It's a setting, not a count of emails.

I don't have anywhere to test this right now, but here's what I think you need:

```
$Outlook = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application  
$OutlookInbox = $Outlook.session.GetDefaultFolder(6)  
$TotalEmailCount = $OutlookInbox.Items.Count

While ($TotalEmailCount -eq 0)  
{  
    Start-Sleep -s 10  
    Write-Host "Waiting for the email"  
    $TotalEmailCount = $OutlookInbox.Items.Count
}  

Write-Host $TotalEmailCount
```

Noting that (as above) you need to be re-checking the item count within your loop or your script will run forever.

Comment: Thanks Mark. It works like charm, this is exactly what I am looking for.

Comment: What is number 6 in line 2 ?

Comment: magic number 6 in like 2 means inbox.
you can use 5 for  sent items or 4 for outbox